# web api convert every response to base64

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

I have a code

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Search()
        {
            return Ok(Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(db.view_users.Take(1)))));
        }
```

I want send to client in base64, but it hard if i must convert manually in every return.

if there a way so i can automatically convert  every return to base 64, how to do that?

so i can just use natural code like this :

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult Search()
        {
            return Ok(db.view_users.Take(1));
        }
```

but still return the same result in base64

thanks

Comment: You can create filter attribute and apply to all action methods

Comment: how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can create [ActionFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) like this:

```
public class Base64FilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override async Task OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (actionExecutedContext.Exception == null)
        {
            var bytes = await actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            actionExecutedContext.Response.Content = new StringContent(base64); 
        }

        await base.OnActionExecutedAsync(actionExecutedContext, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

and then mark you controllers with this attribute or register as global filter.

If you are using OWIN You can also create OWIN midelware for that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/.